# Laravel 5.2 token mismatch and middleware error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware, laravel-authorization

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and doing all authentication manually. So, although everything works, but I get a `token mismatch` error and the reason is that I'm not passing my routes through the `web` middleware in my routes file:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['web']],function (){
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    })->name('home');
});
Route::social();
```

where `Route::social();` is

```
public function social() {

    $this->post('/signup',['uses'=>'UserController@postSignUp','as'=>'signup']);
    $this->post('/signin',['uses'=>'UserController@postSignIn','as'=>'signin']);
    $this->get('/dashboard',function() {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->middleware('auth');
}
```

But if I move `Route::social();` to the web middleware group, it doesn't count errors and so return empty errors even if there are. How do I get around with it? I want both things!

I've the token field in my form using `{!! Form::token() !!}`

Answer (score 1):

You are probably manually adding an `$error` array to your view, the [`web`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php#L26) middleware will do the same thing so this will be overwritten. The [`web`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php#L26) middleware group includes [`\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession`](https://github.com/illuminate/view/blob/master/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php) which creates an error variable in the views with validation errors.

There are two ways to fix this. One is to only include the [`\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php) middleware for this route. The other, wich I would prefer, is to add the route to the `web` middleware group, but use another name for your array with errors.